# How to determine the symbols and styles chosen by Swift Charts

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-charts

I'm curious, is there a way to predict or query the style and symbols that Swift Charts will use when using `.foregroundStyle(by:)`, `.symbol(by:)`, etc?

The reason I need to know is that I have UI elements outside the Chart that need to match those choices. I know that I could work at this from the other end - I could override the defaults and would therefore know what's being used; but I'm asking what to do if I'd rather keep the sensible Apple-provided defaults.